# Getting a document and window is not defined error in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, next.js

I initially had a create-react-app working and I decided to migrate the app to NextJS. So far everything is good but I have a utility file (`src/lib/utils.ts`) where I'm getting an error that I can't quite figure out as I am new to NextJS.

```js
const setReferrer = () => {
    const referrer = document.referrer;
    ...
};
```

This worked in create-react-app but in NextJS I'm getting this error:

> Server Error
> ReferenceError: document is not defined
>
> This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will
> be displayed in the terminal window.

When I comment this code out, I also get errors when getting the resolution of the device:

```js
const setResolution = () => {
    const resolution =
        window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio + 'x' + window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio;
    ...
};
```

In which case it's the `window` not being defined.

Is it a different process for getting these data with NextJS compared to create-react-app?

Comment: Where are you calling these functions? You may need to wrap them in an effect hook to ensure they run on the client-side

Comment: @Phil on CRA, I have a utility file to initialize sentry.io from the entry point `index.js` before rendering the app which seems to work because it's CSR so those objects are defined. I tried to copy the same utility file on the NextJS app and initialized sentry.io from the `_app.js` file which I believe is also the entry point.